# open pdf with openwith option android

Tags: android, pdf

I have a pdf opened with my own application. Now when user click on a button I am showing openwith options of application/pdf. Now the user select his choice (for example adobe reader) and the opened pdf file must be shown in user choice (adobereader in this case). I have bytearray and input stream with me for the opened PDF.

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: hello, it will show by default. but what you tried so far?

Comment: openwith window will  be shown by default, but when I click a button in my app i m showing openwith intent and now user chooses adobe reader, now i want to show the same pdf document pdf bytes in adobereader. Actually Im newbee to android and unable to start or identify which event fires here....

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ filename);
Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
try {
startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
// Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
}
```

**EDIT 1**

```
 OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out.pdf");
 out.write(bArray);
 out.close();
```

After creating pdf,

```
File file = new File("filepath");
Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
try {
startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
// Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
File myFile = new File("out.pdf");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        out.write(bytArray);
        out.close();

        Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(myFile),"application/pdf");
        target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
try {
startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
// Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
}
```

this may helps you

**EDIT 3**

The following code was tested by myself and it's working as u want

> Create the pdf file:

```
File resolveMeSDCard  = new File("/sdcard/download/media/output.pdf");

 public void createPDF()
  {
      byte[] byt = new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5};

      File mediaDir = new File("/sdcard/download/media");
      if (!mediaDir.exists()){
          mediaDir.mkdir();
      }

      FileOutputStream fos;
    try {

        //File resolveMeSDCard = new File("/sdcard/download/media/output.pdf");
        resolveMeSDCard.createNewFile();
        fos = new FileOutputStream(resolveMeSDCard);
        fos.write(byt);
        fos.close();
         System.out.println("Your file has been written");  
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
         System.out.println("Your file has not been written");  
    }

  }
```

> Open the pdf file:

```
  public void openPDF() 
  {
      Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(resolveMeSDCard),"application/pdf");
        target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
try {
startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
// Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
}   
  }
```

> manifest.xml

add the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

`Note :`
1.Change the code order as you want.

2.call createPDF() and then OpenPDF().

This is working code.

Comment: Thanks for the response Sathish.. but my file is not physically available,, I have the file in bytearray and inputstream as well...

Comment: then first create pdf from your byteArray . see my EDIT 1

Comment: what is filepath in File... where I don't have any file instead I have only out.pdf...

Comment: I implemented the same earlier too... but the error "The document path is not valid" is displayed..

Comment: It is not working as I dont have file in any path...and targeting devices with no SD card or no space...So content provider is the only solution it seems...

Comment: did you finished using ContentProvider?

Comment: I succeeded in creating content provider with bytearray but adobereader is opening the file, displaying pagenumbers too, but not showing the content of pages..

Answer (score 0):

when clicked on openwith in app.. im using content provider as my file is not available physically...

```
 try {
            createCachedFile(this, attachmentFileName, bytes);
            startActivity(pdfOpenWith(this, attachmentFileName, bytes));
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not available on this device.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

public  void createCachedFile(Context context, String fileName, byte[] content) throws IOException {
    File cacheFile = new File(context.getCacheDir() + File.separator + fileName);
    cacheFile.createNewFile();
    BufferedOutputStream bostream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(cacheFile));
    bostream.write(content);
    bostream.flush();
    bostream.close();
}

public static Intent pdfOpenWith(Activity context, String fileName, byte[] bytecontent)
{
    Intent pdfintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    //pdfintent.setType("application/pdf");
    Uri contenturi = Uri.parse("content://" + AttachFileProvider.AUTHORITY + "/" + fileName);
    Toast.makeText(context, fileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
    pdfintent.setDataAndType(contenturi, "application/pdf");
    pdfintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    pdfintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    return pdfintent;
```